# after adding socialite package laravel 5.5 Login stops working

Tags: laravel

After I adding socialite package Laravel 5.5 Login stops working.. its Gives Error Message

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.

I have hosted it on "SSL" enabled server.

Comment: clear your browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code of login  and make sure it includes a

{!! csrf_field() !!}

to provide a "CSRF Protection" feature.(by L5.5 defualt)

or you may need to clear the cache content again on your browser.

Comment: tried clearing cache and already have csrf field, actually it was working fine before the socialite package installing but after install stops working, still not work